# How do I access hash data in sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am attempting to access hash data in sinatra:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

class List 
   def self.items
   return items = {

   :something1 =>  { :attribute1 => "somestring1", :attribute2 => "somestring2" },
   :something2 =>  { :attribute1 => "somestring3", :attribute2 => "somestring4" }

   }
   end
end

list = List.items

get '/' do
   list.each do |name, meta|
      "#{name}<br>#{meta[:attribute1]}<br>#{meta[:attribute2]}<br><br>"
   end
end
```

I expected sinatra to print the hash data of each hash. However, it printed just the hashes instead (probably because I called `list.each`). The console prints the expected result when I use `puts`.

To clarify, the desired result is:

```
something1
somestring1
somestring2

something2
somestring3
somestring4
```

How do I make sinatra print just the variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `each`, and then join the result to return a string:

```
get '/' do
  list.map do |name, meta|
    "#{name}<br>#{meta[:attribute1]}<br>#{meta[:attribute2]}<br><br>"
  end.join
end
```

`each` returns the array you call it on. [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) will return a new array, transforming each entry in the Enumerable according to your block.

Comment: Thanks! I've never heard of `map`. So, I just used `each`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
get '/' do
   s = ''
   list.each do |name, meta|
      s << "#{name}<br>#{meta[:attribute1]}<br>#{meta[:attribute2]}<br><br>"
   end
   return s
end
```

Comment: Note that in your original question you misspelled the key for somestring4.

Comment: I'm shocked that `somestring4` was left off. Theoretically, would that be a bug?